# Why does $request->get() return null?

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel

I am sending a post request to laravel via an angularjs form,

AngularJS:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="app.person.firstName">
<input type="text" ng-model="app.person.lastName">
```

---

```
$http.post('/tests', person).success(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }).error(function() {
    console.log("Oh no!");
});
```

Laravel with `$request->all()` (works):

```
 $input = $request->all();
 $first = $input['firstName'];
 $last = $input['lastName'];
 ....
 return json_encode($this->data_object);
 // returns correct object
```

Laravel with `$request->get()` (returns `null`):

```
 $input = $request->get('firstName');
 return json_encode($input);
 // returns null
```

Why does `$request->get('firstName')` return `null` when `$request->all()` returns an object with a `firstName` index?

Comment: So is it correct that you're sending a POST request then you're being surprised there is nothing in GET?

Comment: I'm not sure `$request->get()` is used for HTTP GET requests.  At least, that's what it seems like according to the docs. `When working on forms with "array" inputs, you may use dot notation to access the arrays:

$input = $request->get('products.0.name');`

Comment: `$request->input()` works, however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's currently a bug in Laravel where `$request->get()` only works for actual `GET` and `POST` data.

It doesn't work when the post body is JSON (which is what Angular does).

You can use `$request->input('firstName')` instead.

Comment: And by currently are you reffering to 4.2?

Comment: seems like this bug is still exist :D laravel 8